# Permissions Error Exporting a table from Google BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Getting the following error as of 2017-07-08 when exporting a table to Cloud Storage.

Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while writing data

Working fine before that date, haven't changed anything in the project, big query or cloud storage.

JobId: alert-basis-89415:bquijob_6adfd86e_15d2de5ce1b

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It was a problem on Google's end. I found a topic in Google groups (can't seem to find it now) where you could supply your details and they applied a hotfix for those accounts before rolling it out proper.

Comment: can you get some details here , otherwise the answer is useless

Comment: Its not entirely useless, at least you know you can try contacting google support, send them a link to this SO question and see what they say

Comment: Thanks @EvanR. That's why I didn't just delete the question, just wish I could find the original google topic with the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error. It was because I was using a bucket in region different from the BQ dataset, and a incorrect bucket URL.
After I ensured following two

- I double checked and fixed specified bucket URL is correct
- I created bucket in same region that the data resides

I was good

Answer (score 1):

It appears the user running the job doesn't have [storage.objects.create](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#object_permissions) permission to the GCS bucket - perhaps something changed with bucket permissions? Is this still recurring, can you explicitly add that user to the bucket ACLs?

Comment: Cheers, the user running the job is the Owner of the project (set in IAM) and I can see in the bucket permissions that owner's of the project have the following permission: 

Storage Legacy Bucket Owner (2 members)

Read and write access to existing buckets with object listing/creation/deletion.

I've tried giving the user storage.objects.create permission and also adding it specifically to the bucket but to no avail.

Haven't changed anything on my end (the job is usually automated using a service account, first time I've even logged in in a while).

Answer (score 0):

Look up the service account's e-mail address, and add the account to the bucket ACL as a writer and file reader:

```
gsutil acl ch -u blabla@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com:W gs://bucket
gsutil acl ch -u blabla@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com:R gs://bucket/1.csv
gsutil acl ch -u blabla@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com:R gs://bucket/2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the service account has the right permissions to do things on that bucket. It's confusing because even if the bucket is public, that doesn't allow write access from just plain old anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. All my IAM grants looked correct.

It turns out it was failing because the SA has permission to create files (object.Creator) but not to overwrite/replace files in the bucket. Because a file by the same name already existed in the bucket it failed until I removed the file (or you can give it permission to overwrite the file).

The error is confusing/misleading though.

> Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while writing data."

Using `bq` cli to show the job details was helpful in debugging this issue.

```
bq show --format=prettyjson --job=true <<job-id>>
```